# PHP - Display data in different time zones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, currency-exchange-rates

Hello stackoverflow community.

I develop a web app and the concept is to display historical currency exchange rates based on time series from past.

For example a user may request exchange rates from 22 May 2020 13:00 to 26 MAY 2020 22:00. Then my backend run a loop and get the rates between those two date times each hour.

All rates in database stored in GMT time zone.

And here is the problem. Let's suppose a user make a request from a time zone offset +10:00. So if this user pick as last date time 26 MAY 2020 22:00, I guess I should grab from my database the rate in 26 MAY 2020 12:00, so to subtract 10 hours.

May this sound stupid, but I'm stuck with this.

What is my logic:

a) Get the users time zone offset via javascript in front-end

```
var get_timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

var hrs = parseInt(-(timezone_offset / 60));

var mins = Math.abs(timezone_offset % 60);

var timezone_offset = hrs + ':' + mins;
```

b) Send users time zone offset to my backend

c) Get rates from my database and convert date stored from GMT to users time zone offset via PHP's Datetime object

```
$date = new \DateTime('2020-05-26 22:00');

$date->modify(-10 hours);

$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Is this right? I won't display wrong rates to my users.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The way I handle datetimes is everyone on the server and in the database is ALWAYS UTC. It expects to receive inputs in UTC and outputs are UTC. The client (the javascript front-end) handles display... so that's what should convert dates to the user's timezone. I use moment-timezone for easily converting from UTC to local time. Storing everything on the server in UTC saves a lot of headaches with confusion & daylight savings time

Comment: Also, no, your solution wouldn't be correct because simply subtracting 10 hours doesn't account for daylight savings time

Comment: @DanielRead Thank you very much Daniel. Also I mentioned there are cities with same UTC but with different time. For example Athens Greece has UTC +02:00 and now is 19:30, Cairo Egypt has UTC +02:00 and now is 18:30. So confusing :)

Comment: Correct, that's because Athens is currently in daylight savings time +1, while Cairo is not. So the database might store a date like 2020-05-28 00:00:00 for both of them as their UTC datetime, but when you convert it into their local time with moment-timezone, Athens would display "2020-05-28 03:00:00" and Cairo would display "2020-05-28 02:00:00" because it takes daylight savings time into account

Comment: @DanielRead Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".  In short, you cannot assume the offset taken *now* from the user is the same one that will apply at any other point in time.

A simple example is for time zones like `America/New_York`, which presently is UTC-4, but will switch to UTC-5 when daylight saving time ends in November.  But besides DST, many time zones have had changes in their *standard* time offsets.

Instead of getting the current numeric offset, get the IANA time zone identifier from the browser.

```js
const tzid = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
// example: "America/New_York", "Asia/Kolkata", "Europe/Athens", etc.
```

Then you can use this identifier with PHP's built-in time zone support.  For example, the following converts from a local time in a given time zone to the equivalent time in UTC:

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime('2020-05-26 22:00', $tz);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matt. You're right. But how we handle with browsers that doesn't support  IANA time zone identifier, like IE 6-10

Comment: @VasileiosTsakalis Try polyfill such as this one https://github.com/formatjs/date-time-format-timezone to support older browsers

Comment: There's also [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect), and [Moment-Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) which has `moment.tz.guess()`.  But really - who is still running IE6?? :)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thank you very much :)